# Lots of identical buttons and (collapsed) divs on the same page. How do I use Jquery so that each button expands the appropriate div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, button

html:

```
<button class='expandotron'></button>
<div class='detail-view'></div>
<button class='expandotron'></button>
<div class='detail-view'></div>
<button class='expand'></button>
<div class='detail-view'></div>
```

the jquery:

```
$('.expandotron').click(function() {
    if($( ".detail-view" ).css('display') != 'none'){
         $( ".detail-view" ).css('display', 'none');
         $( ".fixed-table-body" ).css('height', '0px'); // ignore this line
         $( ".table-pad ").css('padding', '0px'); // ignore this line
      } else {
         $( ".detail-view" ).css('display', 'table-row');
         $( ".fixed-table-body" ).css('height', 'auto'); //ignore this line
         $( ".table-pad" ).css('padding', '12px'); // ignore this line
      }
```

This just links all of the buttons to all of the divs

Comment: So where do the elements with the classes `fixed-table-body` and `table-pad` come into play here? And is each button supposed to affect the `detail-view` div right after it, or is it supposed to work some other way?

Comment: Seems like you'd want to use ids to uniquely identify each element. Classes or looking at the position of the node in the DOM tree might be made to work, but would be brittle.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the jQuery [`next`](https://api.jquery.com/next/) selector to find the next element that matches a certain criteria. For instance, to get the next `div` with the class `detail-view` you can use `$(this).next( ".detail-view" )` and so on inside of your `click` event, so that your final jQuery code would look something like:

```
$('.expandotron').click(function() {
    if($(this).next( ".detail-view" ).css('display') != 'none'){
         $(this).next( ".detail-view" ).css('display', 'none');
         $(this).next( ".fixed-table-body" ).css('height', '0px');
         $(this).next( ".table-pad ").css('padding', '0px');
      } else {
         $(this).next( ".detail-view" ).css('display', 'table-row');
         $(this).next( ".fixed-table-body" ).css('height', 'auto');
         $(this).next( ".table-pad" ).css('padding', '12px');
      }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your input, guys :) I ended up using this:

```
 $( ".expandotron" ).each(function( index, element ) {

       $(element).click(function(){
           if( $( ".detail-view:eq("+String(index)+")" ).css('display') == 'none'){
            $( ".detail-view:eq("+String(index)+")" ).css('display', 'table-row');
            $( ".fixed-table-body:eq("+String(index)+")").css('height', 'auto');
            $( ".table-pad:eq("+String(index)+")" ).css('padding', '12px');
        } else {
            $( ".detail-view:eq("+String(index)+")" ).css('display', 'none');
            $( ".fixed-table-body:eq("+String(index)+")").css('height', '0');
            $( ".table-pad:eq("+String(index)+")" ).css('padding', '0px');
        }
      }); 

    });
```